# How to find DST Cutover time

Tags: go, dst

Is there any easy way to find DST cutover time for particular Timezone(Say America/New_York) in given Time range?
I know I can write the custom logic to iterate over each hours, calculate the offset for each hour and compare it with previous hour offset. If offset is diff, that will be DST cutover time
Or I can use IANA database

But I don't want to go with these approaches. I am more interested in knowing if there is any inbuilt functionality in Go or any package that provides such functionality.

Comment: Go does use this information internally (see the `tx` field of the `time.Location` type and associated logic–in the `time/zoneinfo.go` file of the standard library) but it's not exposed to the general clients. Still, you may look at how it is implemented and write your own code doing the same thing (or just copy the code and modify it if you're OK with its licensing terms).

Comment: While we're at it, [the language is called Go](https://golang.org/doc/faq#go_or_golang). You don't say JavaLang, PythonLang etc.

Comment: yeah..i investigated that part. There is lookup function in Location that Go calls to check for DST timing. But problem is its not exposed. And As I mentioned, I don't want to reinvent the wheel and write the same logic. I wanted to check if some package already provides this functionality

Comment: «I wanted to check if some package already provides this functionality»–then your question specifically violates [SO rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: …to not sound dismissive, open-ended questions and questions provoking opinionated answers could be asked using venues other than SO; [there are plenty of them](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki#the-go-community).

Answer (score -2):

To find the DST cutover time, you can use the following steps:

Determine the time zone you are in.
Find out whether or not your time zone observes Daylight Saving Time (DST).
If your time zone does observe DST, find out the start and end dates for DST.
The DST cutover time is the time at which clocks are set forward or backward to observe DST.
For example, in the United States, most time zones observe DST. The start date for DST is the second Sunday in March at 2:00 AM local time. The end date for DST is the first Sunday in November at 2:00 AM local time.

Therefore, the DST cutover time in the United States is:

Spring forward: Second Sunday in March at 2:00 AM local time
Fall back: First Sunday in November at 2:00 AM local time
In India, DST is not observed. Therefore, there is no DST cutover time in India.